# Solr (Admin): In what unit is transaction_logs_total_size represented?

Tags: solr

Probably a simple question but I can't find the answer on google:

In the Solr Admin UI under 'UPDATEHANDLER' for my Solr core it lists some metrics and one is called `transaction_logs_total_size` - currently showing `2192`.

I don't know if that metric is measured in MB, GB or maybe 'Documents'. I cannot access the server's transaction logs and have a look at their file properties.

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea, but let's try to find out (if you just want to cut to the chase, the answer is at the bottom)!

We'll start [by searching for `transaction_logs_total_size`](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=transaction_logs_total_size) at the [lucene-solr Github Repository](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=transaction_logs_total_size). This leads us to the only reference being in [DirectUpdateHandler2.java](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/master/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/update/DirectUpdateHandler2.java#L899):

```
if (this.ulog != null) {
  lst.add("transaction_logs_total_size", ulog.getTotalLogsSize());
  lst.add("transaction_logs_total_number", ulog.getTotalLogsNumber());
}
```

Apparently the information is retrieved from whatever object `ulog` points to. The first reference to `ulog` in the file is a check (so ulog seems to be defined in the base class of DirectUpdateHandler2):

```
UpdateLog existingLog = updateHandler.getUpdateLog();

if (this.ulog != null && this.ulog == existingLog) {
```

But since there's a comparison between types here, we can probably assume that ulog points to an object of the `UpdateLog` class. Since UpdateLog wasn't imported explicitly, it has to reside at the same directory path as the other class.

So we open [UpdateLog.java](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/master/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/update/UpdateLog.java#L204) and search for `getTotalLogsSize`, which gives us a hit:

```
public long getTotalLogsSize() {
  long size = 0;
  synchronized (this) {
    for (TransactionLog log : logs) {
      size += log.getLogSize();
    }
  }
  return size;
}
```

This shows that `getTotalLogSize` is a sum of all the `TransactionLogs` available in the `logs` property. This is defined as `protected final Deque<TransactionLog> logs = new LinkedList<>();`, so the class that exposes the `getLogSize` method is `TransactionLog`. This class isn't imported either, so we can assume that is lives in the same directory as well, and find [TransactionLog.java](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/master/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/update/TransactionLog.java#L586). Searching that for `getLogSize` gives us:

```
public long getLogSize() {
  if (tlogFile != null) {
    return tlogFile.length();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

.. which seems to indicate that whatever is being returned, is the value returned from the `length()` method on the `tlogFile`. Searching for `tlogFile` shows that it's defined as `File tlogFile;`, and finally, `File` is imported from the standard Java library: `import java.io.File;`.

We've finally reached the end of our exploration - [java.io.File and .length()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#length--):

> Returns the length of the file denoted by this abstract pathname. The return value is unspecified if this pathname denotes a directory.
>
> **Returns**:
>
> The **length, in bytes,** of the file denoted by this abstract pathname, or 0L if the file does not exist.

**Conclusion**: The value is the **total number of bytes** consumed by all the  active transaction log files.